# How to get the right coordinate depending on which side gets raycasted?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay so i added a image to this description, so that the problem gets a bit clearer.

I have a `Parent Object` that contains of three `Blocks`.
The parent has a combined Mesh of those three blocks.

The player (blue circle) is able to destroy the blocks. For this i have a `raycast`, send from the player in the direction he's facing and the return the position of the `hit.point`.

When the player stands at Player Pos 1, the hit.point might be something like `X = 0.5` and `Z = 0.5` (we ignore Y for this example).

So i need to do something like:

```
float xx = hit.point.x + (1 - (hit.point.x % 1));
```

then `xx = 1`.

i can do then the same thing for z.

But:

When the player is at Player Pos 2, this doesn't work.

Then xx would be 4 and not 3 (which would be needed).

I thought about just checking, if the player's `transform.position.x` is smaller or larger then `hit.point.x`, but there's also a problem with this:

> if the player destroy the block at x=2 z=1, and than walks in
>   the middle between the two remaining blocks and then faces the block at x=1 z=1 the result would be x=2 and so he couldn't destroy the block on the left side.

If something isn't clear, i'm very sorry, english isn't my first language.

I hope someone could help me with this!

[image]

Comment: So, you need the Absolute Value (not the signed value)?

Comment: Like `float xx = hit.point.x + (1 - (Math.Abs(hit.point.x) % 1));` ?

Comment: It might be easier to not combine the boxes, and use the hit.transform.position instead of hit.point.

Comment: @LeoBartkus thats not possible, i have some more in my project.

Answer (score 1):

So for simplicity we only consider the X-Z plane and put your parent object at the origin, and assume the size of your "blocks" are 1 unit * 1 unit.
The player is at point P, and the raycast hit-point is H. We add a very small offset to the vector PH (something like 0.001 * PH.normalized), so it would fall inside the block. Then, we use the `Mathf.FloorToInt` method to determine which block the player hits. The code would be something like:

```
Vector3Int GetBlock(Vector3 playerPos, Vector3 hitPoint)
{
    var rayVec = hitPoint - playerPos;
    var finalVec = hitPoint + rayVec.normalized * 0.001f;
    return new Vector3Int(Mathf.FloorToInt(finalVec.x), Mathf.FloorToInt(finalVec.y), Mathf.FloorToInt(finalVec.z));
}
```

Here is a graphical explaination (P is the player, H is the hit-point, HN is the offset (exagerated for explanatory purpose)):[image]

There are, however, minor defects to this solution:
First, it does not take care of rotations, translation and scaling of the parent object. You should do some math in order to put everything under the local coordinate system of the parent object.
Secondly, it doesn't work when the hit-point is near the edge or joints of blocks (because the offset would lead you outside the block), but this is really rare (as long as you keep floating point percision in a reasonable range).